# graphite: Display Sum of Data Since Midnight

Tags: time-series, graphite, grafana

I have a grafana dashboard display today's registered users. I want a "singlestat" board start calculate from midnight of last night, regardless of the time range I chose.

I tried `summarize()` or `timeStack()` but didn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sovled.

Graph -> Edit -> Time Range

use

```
now/d
```